# How to dynamically create multiple jquery datatables?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, datatable

I'm having trouble figuring out the best way to create dynamically create multiple jquery datatables.

I want to display all the tables inside a certain MySQL database as datatables on a webpage. I currently have a php script that serves information about one table to my javascript file. However, I have to specify inside the php script which table I want to display which means I can't use the same script for all the tables in the database. In addition, the table names will constantly be changing inside the database.

Ideally, I would like for me to be able to do something like this:

```
dbtables = [json output from php script with a list of all tables]
for(var i = 0; i < dbtables.length; i++) {
    [CREATE HTML FOR JQUERY DATATABLE]
    [POPULATE DATATABLE FROM AJAX SOURCE USING PHP SCRIPT and pass in dbtables[i] as table name]
}
```

But I'm not sure how to do that (or if it's even the best way).

I am using this script:
http://www.datatables.net/development/server-side/php_mysql

In addition, since each table will have different data, do I need to specify a different document ID for each table in [CREATE HTML FOR JQUERY DATABLE] and how do I go about doing that if needed?

Comment: Did you read through this example: http://www.datatables.net/examples/basic_init/multiple_tables.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually figured out my problem by creating one request that gave me the names of all the tables in my database and then using a `for` loop to go through all those tables and get information. I was trying to do this all in one request, but this worked just as well.